# MySQLdb install under Mac OSX 10.5, Python 2.7

Tags: mysql, mysql-python, python-2.7

I'm trying to get MySQL-Python 1.2.3 running under Leopard on my MacBook Pro for Python 2.7 (64 bit). I've tried building and installing from source along with easy_install with no luck. When installing from source, I have modified mysql_config.path in setup_posix.py as suggested in another related answer to

`mysql_config.path = "/usr/local/mysql-5.1.41-osx10.5-x86/bin/mysql_config"`

The build and install seems to go ok. Yet after typing 'import MySQLdb' in Python, I get the following.

```
>>> import MySQLdb
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.5-fat3.egg/_mysql.py:3: UserWarning: Module _mysql was already imported from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.5-fat3.egg/_mysql.pyc, but /Users/diehl4/Downloads/MySQL-python-1.2.3 is being added to sys.path
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3/egg/_mysql.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3/egg/_mysql.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/diehl4/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.5-fat3.egg-tmp/_mysql.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /Users/diehl4/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.5-fat3.egg-tmp/_mysql.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Any thoughts on what might be the issue? I'm running out of ideas. 
Here is the information from the build:

```
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.macosx-10.5-fat3-2.7
copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-fat3-2.7
creating build/lib.macosx-10.5-fat3-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-fat3-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-fat3-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-fat3-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-fat3-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-fat3-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-fat3-2.7/MySQLdb
creating build/lib.macosx-10.5-fat3-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-fat3-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-fat3-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-fat3-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-fat3-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-fat3-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-fat3-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-fat3-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-10.5-fat3-2.7
gcc-4.0 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Dversion_info=(1,2,3,'final',0) -D__version__=1.2.3 -I/usr/local/mysql-5.1.41-osx10.5-x86/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.5-fat3-2.7/_mysql.o -g -Os -arch i386 -fno-common -D_P1003_1B_VISIBLE -DSIGNAL_WITH_VIO_CLOSE -DSIGNALS_DONT_BREAK_READ -DIGNORE_SIGHUP_SIGQUIT -DDONT_DECLARE_CXA_PURE_VIRTUAL
In file included from _mysql.c:36:
/usr/local/mysql-5.1.41-osx10.5-x86/include/my_config.h:1050:1: warning: "HAVE_WCSCOLL" redefined
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:8,
                 from pymemcompat.h:10,
                 from _mysql.c:29:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:881:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
gcc-4.0 -isysroot / -g -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup build/temp.macosx-10.5-fat3-2.7/_mysql.o -L/usr/local/mysql-5.1.41-osx10.5-x86/lib -lmysqlclient_r -lz -lm -lmygcc -o build/lib.macosx-10.5-fat3-2.7/_mysql.so -arch i386
```

And the information from the install:

```
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing MySQL_python.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to MySQL_python.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to MySQL_python.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'MySQL_python.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching 'MANIFEST'
warning: no files found matching 'ChangeLog'
warning: no files found matching 'GPL'
writing manifest file 'MySQL_python.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-fat3-2.7/MySQLdb
running build_ext
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3/egg
copying build/lib.macosx-10.5-fat3-2.7/_mysql.so -> build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3/egg
copying build/lib.macosx-10.5-fat3-2.7/_mysql_exceptions.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3/egg
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3/egg/MySQLdb
copying build/lib.macosx-10.5-fat3-2.7/MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3/egg/MySQLdb
copying build/lib.macosx-10.5-fat3-2.7/MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3/egg/MySQLdb
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3/egg/MySQLdb/constants
copying build/lib.macosx-10.5-fat3-2.7/MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3/egg/MySQLdb/constants
copying build/lib.macosx-10.5-fat3-2.7/MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3/egg/MySQLdb/constants
copying build/lib.macosx-10.5-fat3-2.7/MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3/egg/MySQLdb/constants
copying build/lib.macosx-10.5-fat3-2.7/MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3/egg/MySQLdb/constants
copying build/lib.macosx-10.5-fat3-2.7/MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3/egg/MySQLdb/constants
copying build/lib.macosx-10.5-fat3-2.7/MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3/egg/MySQLdb/constants
copying build/lib.macosx-10.5-fat3-2.7/MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3/egg/MySQLdb/constants
copying build/lib.macosx-10.5-fat3-2.7/MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3/egg/MySQLdb
copying build/lib.macosx-10.5-fat3-2.7/MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3/egg/MySQLdb
copying build/lib.macosx-10.5-fat3-2.7/MySQLdb/release.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3/egg/MySQLdb
copying build/lib.macosx-10.5-fat3-2.7/MySQLdb/times.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3/egg/MySQLdb
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3/egg/_mysql_exceptions.py to _mysql_exceptions.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3/egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3/egg/MySQLdb/connections.py to connections.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3/egg/MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3/egg/MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py to CLIENT.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3/egg/MySQLdb/constants/CR.py to CR.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3/egg/MySQLdb/constants/ER.py to ER.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3/egg/MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py to FIELD_TYPE.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3/egg/MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py to FLAG.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3/egg/MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py to REFRESH.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3/egg/MySQLdb/converters.py to converters.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3/egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py to cursors.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3/egg/MySQLdb/release.py to release.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3/egg/MySQLdb/times.py to times.pyc
creating stub loader for _mysql.so
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3/egg/_mysql.py to _mysql.pyc
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3/egg/EGG-INFO
copying MySQL_python.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3/egg/EGG-INFO
copying MySQL_python.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3/egg/EGG-INFO
copying MySQL_python.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3/egg/EGG-INFO
copying MySQL_python.egg-info/top_level.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3/egg/EGG-INFO
writing build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3/egg/EGG-INFO/native_libs.txt
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
creating dist
creating 'dist/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.5-fat3.egg' and adding 'build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3/egg' to it
removing 'build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3/egg' (and everything under it)
Processing MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.5-fat3.egg
Copying MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.5-fat3.egg to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Adding MySQL-python 1.2.3 to easy-install.pth file
```

Answer (score 0):

And here's the answer. I started with a 64 bit install of Python and a 32 bit install of MySQL. I just discovered the latter. Installing a 32 bit version of Python 2.7 made the above issue go away.